# Different execution speed in Cucumber and Specflow

Tags: visual-studio, testing, cucumber, specflow, katalon-studio

I am new in the software testing domain and I had a question regarding the execution speed of the test cases.
I created some test cases using Cucumber(Java language) and Specflow (C# language), where Cucumber is run in Katalon Studio and Specflow is run in Visual Studio.

However, when executing these test cases, I get different results in terms of executing speed. For example, running a test case for a specific feature in Cucumber takes 30 seconds, while in Specflow for the same feature it takes 8 seconds.

May I ask you what are some factors that affects the executing speed of the test cases?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to pin down what is the main factor affecting test case speed. It could be any of the following (and maybe more):

- hardware (RAM, CPU)
- network speed
- programming languages underneath the test framework (C#, Java, Groovy)
- frameworks themselves (Cucumber vs Specflow, Katalon vs Visual Studio)